# What is the best way to use the same navbar and footer on multiple pages on the website without any frameworks?

Tags: javascript, html

There are about 10-15 pages on the website. Currently each page contains the same navbar and footer HTML syntax and I want to remove all that repetitive code but don't know what the best way to do it is. I want to reuse the same HTML navbar and footer code on all pages.

The website is not using any external library or framework other than Bootstrap with jQuery.

I read about jQuery `.load()` but it is deprecated and I would like to avoid jQuery or any external libraries/frameworks as much as possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could write all the HTML, cut and paste it as a string in a JS function, each page could have a `<div id="footer"></div>` and you could set it's `innerHTML` with the string that's in your javascript. Note that this or any similar approach might have an impact on your site's searchability. I don't imagine a search engine's crawlers are running javascript and thus won't find anything in your header or footer.

Comment: You could build a custom WebComponent using vanilla javascript, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements https://dev.to/bennypowers/lets-build-web-components-part-1-the-standards-3e85 Could be tough to support older browsers, but if that isn't an issue, then you should be good to go!

Comment: iframes work without js, and you can embed them seamlessly.

Comment: this is exactly one of the reasons SPAs use frameworks like React. +1 on @CoreyOgburn 's idea. thats a good way to do it.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: heads-up: google has crawled js-added content for about 10 years now.

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted. I couldn't find a similar question asked after 2015 or so. And almost all of them had a jQuery way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways...

1. In case you are using any web server, some of the webservers have feature to include one page into another page using using template engine they use.
2. You can write the code for navbar in some html file and request that file using XMLHttpRequest and append the contents into existing HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
...text before...
<OBJECT data="file_to_include.html">
Warning: file_to_include.html could not be included.
</OBJECT>
...text after...
```

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/struct/includes.html#include-files